# Error during Sync: Broken pipe issue in Android Studio on Mac OS

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-install-apk, android-studio-3.2, android-studio-3.3

Suddenly having this issue in Android Studio. Tried both in Android Studio 3.2 and 3.3 version the same issue. Application running properly in Android emulator but not working for real Android device. Showing this error when trying to run the application:

```
Error during Sync: Broken pipe

Session 'app': Error Installing APK
```

Tried [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config) but not working for me. As per their direction updated the `studio.vmoptions` and `idea.propertis` file but still no luck. Here is the updated `studio.vmoptions` file:

```
-Xmx2048m
-Xms256m
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m
-XX:+UseCompressedOops
-Djava.net.preferIPv6Addresses=true
```

and `idea.propertis` file:

```
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# Uncomment this option if you want to customize path to user installed plugins folder. Make sure
# you're using forward slashes.
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# idea.plugins.path=${idea.config.path}/plugins
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# Maximum file size (kilobytes) IDE should provide code assistance for.
# The larger file is the slower its editor works and higher overall system memory requirements are
# if code assistance is enabled. Remove this property or set to very large number if you need
# code assistance for any files available regardless their size.
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
idea.max.intellisense.filesize=2500
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# This option controls console cyclic buffer: keeps the console output size not higher than the
# specified buffer size (Kb). Older lines are deleted. In order to disable cycle buffer use
# idea.cycle.buffer.size=disabled
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
idea.cycle.buffer.size=1024
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configure if a special launcher should be used when running processes from within IDE.
# Using Launcher enables "soft exit" and "thread dump" features
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
idea.no.launcher=false
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# To avoid too long classpath
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
idea.dynamic.classpath=false
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# There are two possible values of idea.popup.weight property: "heavy" and "medium".
# If you have WM configured as "Focus follows mouse with Auto Raise" then you have to
# set this property to "medium". It prevents problems with popup menus on some
# configurations.
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
idea.popup.weight=heavy
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# Use default anti-aliasing in system, i.e. override value of
# "Settings|Editor|Appearance|Use anti-aliased font" option. May be useful when using Windows
# Remote Desktop Connection for instance.
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
idea.use.default.antialiasing.in.editor=false
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# Disabling this property may lead to visual glitches like blinking and fail to repaint
# on certain display adapter cards.
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
sun.java2d.noddraw=true
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# Removing this property may lead to editor performance degradation under Windows.
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
sun.java2d.d3d=false
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# Workaround for slow scrolling in JDK6
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
swing.bufferPerWindow=false
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# Removing this property may lead to editor performance degradation under X Window.
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
sun.java2d.pmoffscreen=false
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# Workaround to avoid long hangs while accessing clipboard under Mac OS X.
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# ide.mac.useNativeClipboard=True
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# Maximum size (kilobytes) IDEA will load for showing past file contents -
# in Show Diff or when calculating Digest Diff
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# idea.max.vcs.loaded.size.kb=20480
```

And the `gradle.properties` file:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

Comment: did you check, Gradle-aware Make is added or not?

Comment: Yes, its added and running in Emulator working fine.